# PAM authentication failed for user "<username>"

Tags: amazon-web-services, hibernate, amazon-rds, aws-fargate, aws-vpc-peering

come here, after attempting so many times.

**Use-Case**:
We are trying to connect to RDS DB intsance from another aws account with RDS IAM authentication token. Abled to connect to db after configuring all the necessary requirement.(creating db user, setting all the previllege to that user, attaching Policy) that work's fine(with just only JDBC url).

But next, When I try to add the hibernate configuration with C3P0 polling strategy with same RDS token method strategy. I am getting an exception

```
PAM authentication failed for user "<username>"
```

I tried lot's of  things but nothing work.

Can anyone help here what I am missing here ? Or what are the possiblity of this error Is it just user and password mis-configuration or what?

Note: We are using ECS fargate application. Also, this same question did't help for me :[psql: FATAL: PAM authentication failed for user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27544308/psql-fatal-pam-authentication-failed-for-user)
that's why raising this with usecase.

```
Connection error: 
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: PAM authentication failed for user "<username>"
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:613) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar:42.2.16]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:161) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar:42.2.16]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:213) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar:42.2.16]
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:51) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar:42.2.16]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:225) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar:42.2.16]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:465) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar:42.2.16]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:264) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar:42.2.16]
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:175) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.5.jar:0.9.5.5]
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:220) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.5.jar:0.9.5.5]
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:206) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.5.jar:0.9.5.5]
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:203) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.5.jar:0.9.5.5]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1176) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.5.jar:0.9.5.5]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1163) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.5.jar:0.9.5.5]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$700(BasicResourcePool.java:44) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.5.jar:0.9.5.5]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1908) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.5.jar:0.9.5.5]
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:696) ~[mchange-commons-java-0.2.19.jar:0.2.19]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was my RDS Token was expired after 15 min and it's was not re-create again automatically. Have implement some of the Datasource and override connection. After that it got generated after the first iteration expiration.